# Android sending image to Server via MultipartEntity - setting Content-type?

Tags: android

I've read many many posts about sending an image to the server from an Android app and Content-type-wise, they are divided in three categories:

a) they dont set the content-type at all and probably somehow their code works

b) they are using deprecated methods

c) they are using completely different approach from the one I've selected.

I would like to send the file over to the server and store it in a folder.

My code is a total patchwork, a butchery job that I managed to come up with after reading lots of posts and articles, here is it:

```
public void uploadImageToServer(String imagePath) throws Exception {

    try {

        // set the http handlers
        httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        localContext = new BasicHttpContext(); // why do I need this?
        postRequest = new HttpPost("http://asd.com/asd.php"); 
        //postRequest.addHeader("Content-type", "image/jpeg"); // - this didnt work

        // deal with the file
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath);
        bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, byteArrayOutputStream); 
        byte[] byteData = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
        //String strData = Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.DEFAULT); // I have no idea why Im doing this
        ByteArrayBody byteArrayBody = new ByteArrayBody(byteData, "image"); // second parameter is the name of the image (//TODO HOW DO I MAKE IT USE THE IMAGE FILENAME?)

        // send the package
        multipartEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
        multipartEntity.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
        multipartEntity.addPart("uploaded_file", byteArrayBody);

        postRequest.setEntity(multipartEntity.build());

        // get the response. we will deal with it in onPostExecute.
        response = httpClient.execute(postRequest, localContext);
        bitmap.recycle();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And the error is:

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
 java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
 java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.http.entity.ContentType
 org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.ByteArrayBody.<init>(ByteArrayBody.java:67)
 org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.ByteArrayBody.<init>(ByteArrayBody.java:87)
```

Comment: Just Check your Server side that if the image is in .png or in .jpg format??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using a library, you need to put it into **/libs** folder.

EDIT:

download httpmime, httpcore and httpclient library from http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi

Comment: I am using a library and it is in the /libs folder. The error says I havent set the Content-type

Comment: No, the error says that not found the part of the library Content-type: Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.http.entity.ContentType

Comment: oh, well first of all sorry for disagreeing with you there. second I am using httpmime-4.3.jar and its in the libs folder, so what do I do

Comment: Go there http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi and download httpmime, httpclient and httpcore, and then try it again

Comment: wow thanks that helped fix the problem. you could edit your answer to add this info to it. Im accepting it.

Answer (score 5):

Use this code to upload image file

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost postMethod = new HttpPost("http://localhost/Upload/index.php");
File file = new File(filePath);
MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();
FileBody contentFile = new FileBody(file);
entity.addPart("userfile",contentFile);
StringBody contentString = new StringBody("This is contentString");
entity.addPart("contentString",contentString);

postMethod.setEntity(entity);
client.execute(postMethod);
```

and in PHP use this code to receive

```
$uploads_dir = '/Library/WebServer/Documents/Upload/upload/'.$_FILES['userfile']['name'];
if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'])) {
    echo $_POST["contentString"]."\n";
    echo  "File path = ".$uploads_dir;
    move_uploaded_file ($_FILES['userfile'] ['tmp_name'], $uploads_dir);
} else {
    echo "\n Upload Error";
    echo "filename '". $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'] . "'.";
    print_r($_FILES);
}
```

Comment: can you help me please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30132225/sending-multiple-data-to-server-in-predefined-format?

Comment: i all the time get such err java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError... i can't solve it...

Answer (score 1):

### Use this code:--

```
public class HttpMultipartUpload {
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "AaB03x87yxdkjnxvi7";

    public String upload(URL url, File file, String fileParameterName,
            HashMap<String, String> parameters) throws IOException {
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        DataOutputStream dos = null;
        DataInputStream dis = null;
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;

        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 20 * 1024;
        try {
            // ------------------ CLIENT REQUEST
            fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);

            // open a URL connection to the Servlet
            // Open a HTTP connection to the URL
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            // Allow Inputs
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            // Allow Outputs
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            // Don't use a cached copy.
            conn.setUseCaches(false);
            // Use a post method.
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                    "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);

            dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\""
                    + fileParameterName + "\"; filename=\"" + mFileName
                    + ".jpg" + "\"" + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes("Content-Type:image/jpg" + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            // create a buffer of maximum size
            buffer = new byte[Math.min((int) file.length(), maxBufferSize)];
            int length;
            // read file and write it into form...
            while ((length = fileInputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                dos.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }

            for (String name : parameters.keySet()) {
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\""
                        + name + "\"" + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(parameters.get(name));
            }

            // send multipart form data necessary after file data...
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);
            dos.flush();
        } finally {
            if (fileInputStream != null)
                fileInputStream.close();
            if (dos != null)
                dos.close();
        }

        // ------------------ read the SERVER RESPONSE
        try {
            dis = new DataInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
            StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();

            String line;
            while ((line = dis.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(line).append('\n');
            }

            System.out.println("Upload file responce:"
                    + response.toString());
            return response.toString();
        } finally {
            if (dis != null)
                dis.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I will wait and see whether its possible to just modify my code to make it work, because I dont wanna start all over again. This is really unfamiliar territory to me

Comment: yeah sure.it works coz i use this code already and works fine

Comment: If it is really work , will be very good, but can you explain please what is it String fileParameterName, HashMap<String, String> parameters, mFileName? Because i can't understand

Comment: its old code now i think we should not do that we have very nice libraries like OkHttp, Retrofit etc. so just use them would be very beneficial and you will have clean code.

Answer (score 0):

If someone just cannot figure out what is going on with headers, take a look at this article http://develop-for-android.blogspot.com/2014/01/using-volley-in-your-application.html It just saved me the day.

Answer (score 0):

Read the source of the file http. Check this solution:

1. Call new MultipartEntity:

   MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE, null, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
2. Add request header

   heads.put("Content-Type", "image/png;charset=utf-8");