# Android StringBody(String) is deprecated

Tags: java, android, apache, http, post

I am trying to send a image to my API. but while using MultipartEntity  StringBody i get error as StringBody(String) is deprecated.

I doesn't work. I so a sample at [Android sending image to Server via MultipartEntity - setting Content-type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20798837/android-sending-image-to-server-via-multipartentity-setting-content-type).

this is the code:

```
try {

    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("api_key", api_key));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("access_token", access_token));

    API api = new API(mApiKey, mApiSecret);        


    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost postMethod = new HttpPost("MY API URL");
    File file = new File(imagePath);
    MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();
    FileBody contentFile = new FileBody(file);

    StringBody api_key       = new StringBody(mApiKey);
    StringBody access_token  = new StringBody(access_token);

    entity.addPart("api_key", api_key);
    entity.addPart("hash", access_token);
    entity.addPart("image", contentFile);

    postMethod.setEntity(entity);
    client.execute(postMethod);



} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 16):

The constructor that you use to create a new instance of `StringBody` is deprecated.

Instead of

```
new StringBody(mApiKey);
```

you should use a `StringBody` constructor with a second parameter that is a `ContentType` like

```
new StringBody(mApiKey, ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN);
```

For further information look at:

http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpmime/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/mime/content/StringBody.html

and

http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/ContentType.html

Comment: Also the The type MultipartEntity is deprecated.

Comment: Yes it is, the documentation can easily be found with Google: http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpmime/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/mime/MultipartEntity.html

Answer (score 2):

**StringBody :**

```
 entity.addPart("api_key", new StringBody(mApiKey,ContentType.TEXT_PLAIN));
```

**MultipartEntity :**

Check : [The type MultipartEntity is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19196292/the-type-multipartentity-is-deprecated)