# MultipartEntityBuilder writeTo() ByteArrayOutputStream

Tags: android, multipartentity, bytearrayoutputstream

I try to use `writeTo()` method in `ByteArrayOutputStream`. Android Studio throw error message:

> Cannot resolve method 'writeTo(java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream)'.

I found this method in a tutorial, I would like to use `MultipartEntityBuilder` to upload image to server.

```
@Override
public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError{
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        mBuilder.build().writeTo(bos);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        VolleyLog.e("IOException writing to ByteArrayOutputStream bos, building the multipart request.");
    }

    return bos.toByteArray();
}
```

Comment: you can send `File` to server.

Comment: `I found this method in a tutorial`

Comment: @DevendraSingh : That is okay, but causes a lot error messages on that way. That is because I would like to use `MultipartEntity`.

Comment: using `MultipartEntity` you can send `file` or [Check here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20798837/android-sending-image-to-server-via-multipartentity-setting-content-type) and [Here](http://www.codepuppet.com/2013/03/26/android-uploading-a-file-to-a-php-server/)